# Struts2 skip xml validation

Tags: java, validation, struts2

i m using xml validation in a struts2 web application. I need to skip validation for 3 input field based on a checkbox value. So, if the checkbox is checked, the validtion rules for the 3 input will be executed, otherwise, no validation.

also, for each of these 3 input, i already create a custom validator class.

i dont know if expression validation can be used in this case, or i have to use expression validation or another custom class.

what is the best way to do that validation?

thanks

Comment: If you want to write custom logic you should implement `Validateable` interface.

Comment: can you explain, do you have an example ?

Comment: do i have to override the validate method in the action class?

Comment: Show the code for your custom validator or validate.

Comment: finally find a solution by mapping my field to a business bean, using a visitor field validation then implementing a custom validator that make all the required validations...

Comment: Is it possible to skip xml validation (via code) from the validate() method?